# Php Xml data not looping through elements in a foreach loop

Tags: php, xml

I have a foreach loop running through an XML file. The loop is counting correctly and running correctly though the data being used from the XML file is always the first part of file. So it runs the right amount of loops but uses the same passes the data for each loop.

Here's my code:

**My XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Suppliers>
    <Supplier>
      <UniqueId>00001</UniqueId>
      <CompanyName>The test account</CompanyName>
      <AccountOpened>2021-08-04T00:00:00</AccountOpened>
      <AccountReference>PAYATEST</AccountReference>
      <VatNumber />
      <CreditLimit>0</CreditLimit>
      <Balance>0</Balance>
      <SupplierInvoiceAddress>
        <Title />
        <Forename />
        <Surname>gfrdg</Surname>
        <Company>Payables Test Account</Company>
        <Description>gfrdg - fg26 2re</Description>
        <Address1>12156</Address1>
        <Address2>bfbf</Address2>
        <Town>firgb</Town>
        <Postcode>fg26 2re</Postcode>
        <County>frjgb</County>
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <Telephone />
        <Fax />
        <Mobile />
        <Email>aaa@aaaa.com</Email>
        <Email2 />
        <Email3 />
        <Website />
        <Birthdate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Notes />
        <TaxCode>1</TaxCode>
        <TradeContact />
        <Activities />
        <Groups />
        <Roles />
      </SupplierInvoiceAddress>
      <SupplierDeliveryAddress>
        <Title />
        <Forename />
        <Surname>gfrdg</Surname>
        <Company />
        <Description>gfrdg - </Description>
        <Address1 />
        <Address2 />
        <Town />
        <Postcode />
        <County />
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <Telephone />
        <Fax />
        <Birthdate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Notes />
        <TaxCode>1</TaxCode>
        <Activities />
        <Groups />
        <Roles />
      </SupplierDeliveryAddress>
      <ChargeCredit xsi:nil="true" />
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <TermsAgreed>true</TermsAgreed>
      <AccountOnHold xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <AccountStatus>0</AccountStatus>
      <Priority>true</Priority>
      <NominalCode>5000</NominalCode>
      <DepartmentInfo>
        <Reference>0</Reference>
        <Name>Default</Name>
        <Number xsi:nil="true" />
      </DepartmentInfo>
      <FixedDiscount>0</FixedDiscount>
      <Analysis1 />
      <Analysis2 />
      <Analysis3 />
      <Memo />
      <OverrideNominalCode xsi:nil="true" />
      <OverrideTaxCode>false</OverrideTaxCode>
      <PaymentDays>30</PaymentDays>
      <PaymentDueFrom>DaysAfterInvoiceDate</PaymentDueFrom>
      <RestrictMailing xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendElectronicInvoice xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendElectronicLetter>false</SendElectronicLetter>
      <SettlementDays>30</SettlementDays>
      <SettlementDiscount>0</SettlementDiscount>
      <Terms />
      <Contacts />
      <TaxCode>0</TaxCode>
      <PaymentGroup xsi:nil="true" />
      <Banks>
        <Bank>
          <BankName />
          <Address1 />
          <Address2 />
          <Town />
          <County />
          <Postcode />
          <AccountName />
          <SortCode />
          <AccountNumber />
          <BACSRef />
          <IBAN />
          <BICSwift />
          <RollNumber />
          <AdditionalRef1 />
          <AdditionalRef2 />
          <AdditionalRef3 />
          <OnlineReceipts>false</OnlineReceipts>
        </Bank>
      </Banks>
    </Supplier>
  </Suppliers>
  <Suppliers>
    <Supplier>
      <UniqueId>00002</UniqueId>
      <CompanyName>The other test account</CompanyName>
      <AccountOpened>2021-08-04T00:00:00</AccountOpened>
      <AccountReference>PAYATEST</AccountReference>
      <VatNumber />
      <CreditLimit>0</CreditLimit>
      <Balance>0</Balance>
      <SupplierInvoiceAddress>
        <Title />
        <Forename />
        <Surname>gfrdg</Surname>
        <Company>Another Test Account</Company>
        <Description>gfrdg - fg26 2re</Description>
        <Address1>12156</Address1>
        <Address2>bfbf</Address2>
        <Town>firgb</Town>
        <Postcode>fg26 2re</Postcode>
        <County>frjgb</County>
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <Telephone />
        <Fax />
        <Mobile />
        <Email>xxx@xxx.com</Email>
        <Email2 />
        <Email3 />
        <Website />
        <Birthdate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Notes />
        <TaxCode>1</TaxCode>
        <TradeContact />
        <Activities />
        <Groups />
        <Roles />
      </SupplierInvoiceAddress>
      <SupplierDeliveryAddress>
        <Title />
        <Forename />
        <Surname>gfrdg</Surname>
        <Company />
        <Description>gfrdg - </Description>
        <Address1 />
        <Address2 />
        <Town />
        <Postcode />
        <County />
        <Country>GB</Country>
        <Telephone />
        <Fax />
        <Birthdate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Notes />
        <TaxCode>1</TaxCode>
        <Activities />
        <Groups />
        <Roles />
      </SupplierDeliveryAddress>
      <ChargeCredit xsi:nil="true" />
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <TermsAgreed>true</TermsAgreed>
      <AccountOnHold xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <AccountStatus>0</AccountStatus>
      <Priority>true</Priority>
      <NominalCode>5000</NominalCode>
      <DepartmentInfo>
        <Reference>0</Reference>
        <Name>Default</Name>
        <Number xsi:nil="true" />
      </DepartmentInfo>
      <FixedDiscount>0</FixedDiscount>
      <Analysis1 />
      <Analysis2 />
      <Analysis3 />
      <Memo />
      <OverrideNominalCode xsi:nil="true" />
      <OverrideTaxCode>false</OverrideTaxCode>
      <PaymentDays>30</PaymentDays>
      <PaymentDueFrom>DaysAfterInvoiceDate</PaymentDueFrom>
      <RestrictMailing xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendElectronicInvoice xsi:nil="true" />
      <SendElectronicLetter>false</SendElectronicLetter>
      <SettlementDays>30</SettlementDays>
      <SettlementDiscount>0</SettlementDiscount>
      <Terms />
      <Contacts />
      <TaxCode>0</TaxCode>
      <PaymentGroup xsi:nil="true" />
      <Banks>
        <Bank>
          <BankName />
          <Address1 />
          <Address2 />
          <Town />
          <County />
          <Postcode />
          <AccountName />
          <SortCode />
          <AccountNumber />
          <BACSRef />
          <IBAN />
          <BICSwift />
          <RollNumber />
          <AdditionalRef1 />
          <AdditionalRef2 />
          <AdditionalRef3 />
          <OnlineReceipts>false</OnlineReceipts>
        </Bank>
      </Banks>
    </Supplier>
  </Suppliers>
</Company>
```

**My Code:**

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
            $dom->loadXml($request->get('data'));
            $supplier_count = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Supplier')->length;

            if ($supplier_count > 0) {
                
                foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Supplier') as $index => $supplier) {
                    
                    $dataArray = array(
                        'reference' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('AccountReference')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'name' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('CompanyName')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'email' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('Email')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'address' => array(
                            'street_1' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Address1')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'street_2' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Address2')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'town' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Town')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'post_code' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Postcode')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'county' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('County')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'country' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Country')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'telephone' => $supplier->getElementsByTagName('SupplierInvoiceAddress')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('Telephone')->item(0)->nodeValue
                        )
                    );
                    
                    if ($account = Account::where('reference', $dataArray['reference'])->first()) {

                        $rules = array(
                            'reference' => 'required|unique:accounts,reference,'.$account->id.',id',
                            'name' => 'required',
                            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$account->id.',account_id'
                        );

                        $messages = array(
                            'reference.required' => 'The company account reference is required.',
                            'reference.unique' => 'This company account reference already exists.',
                            'name.required' => 'The company name is required.',
                            'email.required' => 'The company must have a valid email address',
                            'email.email' => 'The email address for this company is not valid.',
                            'email.unique' => 'The email address for this company already exists.'
                        );

                        $validator = Validator::make($dataArray, $rules, $messages);

                        if ($validator->passes()) {
                            
                            $account = Account::find($account->id);
                            $account->name = $dataArray['name'];
                            $account->save();

                            // Save the address
                            $address = Address::where('account_id', $account->id)->first();
                            if($address) {
                                $address->street_1 = $dataArray['address']['street_1'];
                                $address->street_2 = $dataArray['address']['street_2'];
                                $address->town = $dataArray['address']['town'];
                                $address->county = $dataArray['address']['county'];
                                $address->post_code = $dataArray['address']['post_code'];
                                $address->telephone = $dataArray['address']['telephone'];                                    
                                $address->save();
                            }

                            // Create a user
                            $user = User::where('account_id', $account->id)->first();
                            $user->email = $dataArray['email'];
                            $user->name = $dataArray['name'];
                            $user->save();

                            return array('Updated Successfully!');

                        } else {

                            // Report error
                            $messages = $validator->messages();
                            return $messages->all();

                        }

                    }  else {

                        // Set field rules
                        $rules = array(
                            'reference' => 'required|unique:accounts',
                            'name' => 'required',
                            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
                        );

                        $messages = array(
                            'reference.required' => 'The company account reference is required.',
                            'reference.unique' => 'This company account reference already exists.',
                            'name.required' => 'The company name is required.',
                            'email.required' => 'The company must have a valid email address',
                            'email.email' => 'The email address for this company is not valid.',
                            'email.unique' => 'The email address for this company already exists.'
                        );

                        $validator = Validator::make($dataArray, $rules, $messages);

                        if ($validator->passes()) {

                            $dataArray['password'] = substr(str_shuffle(sha1($dataArray['email'].spl_object_hash($this).microtime(true))), 0, 10);

                            // Create account
                            $account = new Account;
                            $account->reference = $dataArray['reference'];
                            $account->name = $dataArray['name'];
                            $account->save();

                            // Save the address
                            
                            $address = new Address;
                            $address->account_id = $account->id;
                            $address->street_1 = $dataArray['address']['street_1'];
                            $address->street_2 = $dataArray['address']['street_2'];
                            $address->town = $dataArray['address']['town'];
                            $address->county = $dataArray['address']['county'];
                            $address->post_code = $dataArray['address']['post_code'];
                            $address->telephone = $dataArray['address']['telephone'];                                
                            $country = Country::where('code', $dataArray['address']['country'])->get()->first();
                            $address->country_id = $country->id;
                            $address->default_tax_code = '0';
                            $address->save();

                            $account->default_address_id = $address->id;
                            $account->save();
                            
                            // Create a user
                            $user = new User;
                            $user->email = $dataArray['email'];
                            $user->password = Hash::make($dataArray['password']);
                            $user->account_id = $account->id;
                            $user->active = 1;
                            $user->name = $dataArray['name'];
                            $user->save();

                            DB::table('role_user')->insert(['role_id' => 2, 'user_id' => $user->id]); 

                            

                            $name = $dataArray['name'];
                            $email = $dataArray['email'];

                            $details = [
                                'name' => $name,
                                'email' => $email,
                                'password' => $dataArray['password'],
                            ];
                            $subject = 'Account Creation Successful!';
                            $from_email = 'noreply@clarion-uk.com';
                            $from_name = 'Clarion';

                            Mail::to($email)->send(new NewAccountEmail($details, $subject, $from_email, $from_name));

                            $re_name = $dataArray['name'];
                            return array($re_name.' - Created Successfully!');

                        } else {

                            // Report error
                            $messages = $validator->messages();
                            return $messages->all();

                        } 
                    }
                    

                }

                return 'Data saved successfully!';
            }
```

The result is that 'UniqueId' 00001 data gets updated in my database twice, the foreach loop is not fetching the 'UniqueId' 00002's data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you were to run this with all the inner workings commented out and simply echoing data in each iteration does it run ok?

Comment: I just found that if I comment out don't have the 'if' statement (Account::where('reference', $dataArray['reference'])) it does run through correctly.  If I comment out everything inside the 'if' statement and only have statement it does not work... Something weird with the 'if' statement

Comment: what does `Account::where('reference', $dataArray['reference'])->first()` return as a value?

Comment: Its database query for Laravel. It looks inside my accounts table for a matching reference number that is pulled from the XML.

Comment: I've never looked at Laravel so can cast no comment. The `IF` statement though is, by your own account, at fault so perhaps investigate the response (var_dump, print_r etc ) ~ find out what you are dealing with and see how it relates to the error?!

Comment: Found the problem.  It was the way I was returning the result of each loop.  Using 'return' stopped the loop.  So created an array and added the results to it in each loop and returned the result at the end.

Comment: I should have spotted that too - glad you sorted it! Just fyi - there are a few refinements that you could do to that code as there is repetition

Comment: Ye I know, got some tidying up to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix it!!! This is how**

The fault lay with how I returned each result or validation error. I was using:
'return' within each loop (you can see this in my code above), which stopped the loop, because when it returned something it stops.

So what I did was create and array before my loop, and in each loop I added my results to the array and at when all loops are completed I just returned the array.

Here's a simple way...

```
$results= array();

foreach ($a as $b) {
    $results[] = 'This loops result';
}

return $results;
```